# do I have to use this.state in React to maintain component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unclear about the use of `this.state` in React components. While I can create `this.state.myvar`, why should not I just create `this.myvar`?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {myvar: 123};

    render() {
        return <span>{this.state.myvar}</span>;
    }
}
```

or

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    myvar = 123;

    render() {
        return <span>{this.myvar}</span>;
    }
}
```

I realize that there are helpers like `this.setState`, but at the end `this.state` is just a convenience, right? Or does it play a bigger role in React? Should I avoid setting properties directly on `this` to store my state? If so, why?

Comment: When you call setState it causes the component to get re-rendered (potentially)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in fact; rather wrong.

`this.state` in a react component is a special React-backed container that is only acknowledged as having been updated when you use `setState`, which triggers a re-render, which *might* cause DOM updates (or not, depending on what React's diff algorithm sees happening in the JS virtual dom).

You can, of course, also use object properties bound to `this`, but changing them does absolutely nothing for the component itself. React doesn't look at your full component instance for changes, it only looks (internally) at the state, and (when changed by parents) at the props.

As such, you can't "create" things like `this.state.myvar` and then expect them to actually exist from lifecycle function to lifecycle function: as a special management construct, any values you tack onto `state` outside of proper `this.setState(...)` calls have undefined behaviour. They might exist, or they might not. If you really are working with the internal state, then you *need* to signal changes via `this.setState({ myvar: value })`.

Of course, that doesn't mean you can't use `this.myvar`, that'll work fine, but changing it will not "do" anything other than literally just that.

When would you use `this.val` instead of state? When your component has to perform operations that lead to an "intermediate" state, neither being one renderable state, nor the next. For instance, when code can update a state value multiple times between renders, during those changes your component is in an intermediate state, and so you don't want it to re-render. In fact, expecting it to can lead to huge bugs:

```
...
doTest() {
  this.setState({ val: this.state.val+1 });
  this.setState({ val: this.state.val+1 });
  this.setState({ val: this.state.val+1 });
},
...
```

This code will **not** yield a `this.state.val` that's 3 higher than before, because state updates are queued, and overwrite each other. Only the last instruction before a re-render "wins". So in that case you'd need something like:

```
...
doTest() {
  var localval = this.state.val;
  localval++;
  localval++;
  localval++;
  this.setState({ val: localval });
},
...
```

And then if we also need that value accessible outside of this function, then we *finally* have a legitimate use for a `this` property:

```
...
doTest() {
  this.accessibleval = this.state.val;
  this.updateValueAFewTimes();
  this.setState({ val: this.accessibleval });
},
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.state` plays a larger role than you realize.

Setting state via `this.setState` triggers the component to re-render (among other things). Otherwise, React would have no way of knowing when something it depends on changed.