# Adding properties on this vs adding properties on this.state. What's the difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, this, react-class-based-component

I know functional components are easier to use than class components but I'm trying to learn doing things using both of them to understand better. So I looked up some examples at official react website.

The Timer example at [reactjs.org/#a-stateful-component](https://reactjs.org/#a-stateful-component) adds `seconds` as a state of component but it adds `interval` directly on as property of `this`.

I wonder if there is difference between both approaches? When should I add a property on `this` instead of adding it as a state?

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 }; //adding as state
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      seconds: state.seconds + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000); //added property on this
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Seconds: {this.state.seconds}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A similar question was asked before refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35904223/8705343

Comment: Oh Thanks. I searched before posting but couldn't find any similar questions. That answer is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

General rule of thumb is. If you want something to change in UI. You update it in state if no UI change is required. You just update the property

Comment: im a react newb, so bear with me, is this an official guideline, or more of a code style?

Comment: I haven't read on official site. It's more like an untold rule I would say. Which is followed across industry. Because, UI changes are resource intensive. So, you change state when UI change is needed.